Noise Analysis and SPICE Simulation of Integrator Amplifier Circuits
I am currently attempting to analyze the noise of the simplest integrator circuit, as shown in Figure 1. The non-inverting input is grounded, and the inverting input is connected to an ideal current source with infinite internal resistance. The feedback capacitor CF is ideal and does not introduce noise, so the noise comes solely from the amplifier itself.

Fig.1 the simplest integrator circuit

Figure 2 shows the noise sources of the integrator circuit.

Since there is an ideal current source at the inverting input, the inverting input should not be grounded, and all current noise inn passes through the feedback capacitor CF.
For the non-inverting input, the current noise inp is short-circuited, and only the voltage noise en plays a role.
As for the voltage noise en, the value of the feedback capacitor CF, or even its impedance variation with frequency, is not important because the phase is not important, so the integrator circuit acts as a buffer, and the output noise it produces is equal to its own noise.

Therefore, the total output noise of the integrator circuit should be the combined result of the noise generated by the current noise inn passing through the CF and the voltage noise en.

Fig.2 noise sources of the simplest integrator circuit

Above is the theoretical analysis, and now let's move on to simulation.
If we short the feedback capacitor, the amplifier circuit is configured as a buffer, and in this case, the total output noise is equal to the voltage noise en. If we add the feedback capacitor, the total output noise should increase due to the presence of the current noise inn, which means that the total input noise is larger than the voltage noise en.
I choose AD8675 as an example to perform noise simulation in LTspice (I have randomly tested several different operational amplifiers, and the results are similar), comparing the total input noise results between the buffer configuration and the integrator configuration, as shown in Figures 3 and 4. The total input noise under the buffer configuration matches the datasheet very well, but the total input noise in the integrator configuration is significantly lower than that in the buffer configuration!

Fig.3 total input noise of buffer configuration, 6.6n @ 1Hz

Fig.4 total input noise of integrator configuration, 0.6n @ 1Hz
My question is is how to explain this phenomenon. Is it due to the way I perform the simulation is wrong, or the non-ideal parameters of the operational amplifier leading to an overly simplified theoretical analysis, or is it a problem with the amplifier's macro model itself?

Edit:
I performed an AC sweep on both configurations. It appears that there is indeed a difference in bandwidth, but it seems to be a bit too large, with a difference of 180dB at 1Hz.

Fig.5 AC sweep of both configurations

Edit: I think maybe it is because I didn't set a proper DC point for the opamp. If I parallel a very large inductor with CF, the results seem to become more reasonable, but I have not yet performed the specific numerical calculations. But fig. 4 and 5 with the cap without a paralleled large inductor is wrong for sure. Additionally, the AC sweep results for both configurations also become similar.

Fig.6 noise of integrator configuration, with a paralleled large inductor, 9u @ 1Hz, 2.8n @ 1kHz

@Voltage Spike , thank you for reply, These four images were created by me, so there is no citation.

Ok Thanks for the clarification

For one, you need to have a DC path to the negative input.
The X1 function block, did you check the power supply voltages it is supplying?
The simulation I did below seems reasonable with the noise at 2.8 nV/rtHz above 1 kHz. The noise from the resistor will be shunted by the capacitor to a level that is insignificant to the total noise as shown in the left panes. With the 100 M resistor, the DC output voltage is -50 mV, well within the operating range of this part.


I believe our simulations have yielded the same results. In Fig. 6, it shows 9 uV/√Hz at 1Hz and 2.8 nV/√Hz at 1kHz. I used an inductor to establish a DC path, which avoids introducing noise from a resistor, but your results tell me that this noise can be neglected, which is great. Thank you so much!

Unfortunately, the AD8675 datasheet doesn't appear to include a graph of current noise density as a function of frequency, which makes it impossible for me to validate the value of the total output noise.

Also, I think maybe the upper pin of C1 should be connected to ground but not the positive pin of V1, in the left simulation. But it should have little impact.

@Qisechuan You would need to download the SPICE model for this part and see what the notes say about what is simulated. Unfortunately, Analog Devices web site is having problems, so can't get to the model download.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/simulation-models/spice-models/ad8675.cir         I'm not familiar with the SPICE model, but the notes don't say anything about parameters.

@Qisechuan The model doesn't have any notes which is unusual. The model has comments where they show how they modeled voltage noise and flicker noise. Nothing indicates current noise modeling, but that may be part of the device models. You would need to set up simulations to see if current noise is modeled.

I think current noise is modeled, otherwise there shouldn't be a larger total input noise under integrator configuration. It seems that the only thing I can do is to simulate the input total noise ( which is equal to the output total noise under integrator configuration ) at 10Hz to see if it is √( (0.3 pA/√Hz * 1/(23.1410Hz*100nF) )^2 + ( 3.37 nV/√Hz )^2 ) = 47.87 nV/√Hz. 0.3 pA/√Hz is current noise at 10Hz, as the datasheet says. 3.37 nV/√Hz is voltage noise at 10Hz, as the datasheet says and we simulated. But the simulated result ( input total noise ) is 276.6 nV/√Hz.

If I didn't make mistakes in the calculation, I think current noise is modeled but uncorrectly, or as you say it is just given by some device models and different from the real world, so not modeled in fact, if I understand correctly.

The differences in noise are probably due to the RC circuit being formed with the internal resistance of the output and also the internal resistance of the input. One way you could find out is do an AC sweep and look at the bandwidth of the amplifier in both configurations.

I performed an AC sweep on both configurations and added fig. 5. It appears that there is indeed a difference in bandwidth, but it seems to be a bit too large, with a difference of 180dB at 1Hz.

I think maybe it is because I didn't set a proper DC point for the opamp.

Shouldn't matter for the noise as much because it's AC.

I parallel a very large inductor with CF in fig.6, and the output noise is much larger, 9u @ 1Hz. And the AC sweep of both configurations become quite similar, though I didn't post the figure.
